leave Active Directory, go back to local users
my PC with Ubuntu is joined to an Active Directory domain, so basically user related management should be done through AD, e.g. password change.
As domain is not working as expected, I would leave/unjoin the AD user management, and go back to standard local user management.
At the moment I can't create users or modify the password, I'm worried about the risk of being locked out of my PC during the operation.
Where can I find a guide to leave/unjoin AD?
Thanks
Andrea

Keep a user logged in while you do this and use a 2nd session to change this. And do not reboot until you see it work. What did you do to acivate AD? if you activated a service stop it and check if that was enough :)

As for joining or leaving an AD that is info you get from the AD software docs.
